# How to redirect to original page after login with remix-auth-auth0

Tags: oauth-2.0, remix.run

Related to : [How to redirect back to original page after login / signup in remix-auth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71907779/how-to-redirect-back-to-original-page-after-login-signup-in-remix-auth)

If a user try to access to a protected routes, I want him to login, and then be redirected to this route.

With remix-auth, I have this in protected route :

```
export let loader: LoaderFunction = async ({ request }) => {
    return await authenticator.isAuthenticated(request, {
        failureRedirect: "/login?redirectTo=/search",
    });
};
```

Then in my login route :

```
export let loader: LoaderFunction = async ({ request }) => {
    return await login(request);
};
```

With function login() to be :

```
export async function login(request: Request) {
    let url = new URL(request.url);
    let returnTo = url.searchParams.get("redirectTo") as string | null;
  
    try {
        // call authenticate as usual, in successRedirect use returnTo or a fallback
        return await authenticator.authenticate("auth0", request, {
            successRedirect: returnTo ?? "/search",
            failureRedirect: "/",
        });
    } catch (error) {
        if (error instanceof Response && error.redirected) {
            const returnToCookie = createCookie("returnToCookie");
            error.headers.append(
                "Set-Cookie",
                await returnToCookie.serialize(returnTo)
            );
        }
        throw error;
    }
}
```

And finally the callback route is :

```
export let loader: LoaderFunction = async ({ request }) => {
    //get the returnTo from the cookie
    const returnToCookie = createCookie("returnToCookie");
    const result = await returnToCookie.parse(request.headers.get("Cookie"));
    let returnTo = (result) ?? "/";

    return await authenticator.authenticate("auth0", request, {
        successRedirect: returnTo,
        failureRedirect: "/",
    });

};
```

The problem is that login() function currently redirect the user to callback url (with the code in url), but with nothing special in cookie, so the callback route use the fallback.

If I try&catch login() function in login route, the erreur obtained is a Response, but not a redirect, so nothing special in the cookie too (and I don't really know what to do with this Response error)

I not sure of what I missed in the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tries, I found the solution :
The login() function return a 302 HTTP code which is a redirection, but do not trigger the `if (error instanceof Response && error.redirected)`

Simply remove `&& error.redirected` of the condition make the redirection work perfectly.